# Angular 4 Operator '==' cannot be applied to types 'Response' and 'ResponseType

Tags: angular

I am trying to do a simple check with strongly typed variables instead of falling back to knowing the number for errors. Is type Response not the thing I should be sending my error function for a post event?

**Solved....** I found my problem, and I am not sure if it is an issue with Visual Studio code or Angular or both. I had never imported the type Response in this specific class. Visual Studio code was giving me all the intelisense and it was compiling correctly.

See Code:

```
(error: Response) =>
      {
        // I have tried error.type as well 
        var message = (error == ResponseType.Error) ? "Cannot connect to login service." : '';

      }
```

Where this does work:

```
(error: Response) =>
          {

            var message = (error.type === 'error') ? "Cannot connect to login service." : '';

          }
```

Comment: You cannot compare Response with ResponseType. Have you tried error.type == ResponseType.error ?

Comment: I found my issue.

Comment: And yes I had tried that

Comment: Does it work with `error === ResponseType.error`?

Comment: @YannBertrand It was a dumb mistake that Visual Studio code allowed me to make, nothing was wrong in code but the editor was being dumb.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to compare the `type` field to the error as @Ludwig said.

Comment: I found my problem it is not code based. It was not importing the Response class and my editor was telling me I was okay but really I was not working with the right class.